# $p’$-group definition.

Tags: group-theory, definition

I know the definition of $p’$-element of a group i.e. elements of a group $G$ with order prime to $p$. What is definition of $p’$-group. I searched it on google but didn’t find. Please given me definition. Thanks.

Comment: Can I say that a group is $p’$- group if ets every element is $p’$-element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group of which the order $|G|$ is prime to $p$. In general, if $\pi$ is a set of primes then $G$ is a $\pi$-group if the primes that divide $|G|$ belong to $\pi$. Similarly, $\pi’$-groups are defined.

Comment: Thanks sir .....

Comment: You are welcome!